# Spring Hibernate rollback failure during auto flush/commit leaving transactional method

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

Well this is my first post so I really must be scratching my head, as the resources here are excellent.

Spring MVC 4.2.5.  hibernate-core-5.1.0  JDK8

I'm having an issue where transaction not rolling back when leaving a called @Transactional method. The method I'm calling has the appropriate settings:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public byte process(CommonDataBlock commonDataBlock) throws Exception   {
```

The method calls dao objects, lets say we save about 8 objects ('to the database') such as:

```
applicationPartyDao.saveApplicationParty(appParty);
```

With the typical dao just doing something like:

```
this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(appParty);
```

At the start, I'm calling the above transactional method 'process' from a normal POJO:

```
        try {
        // Database transaction starts/ends here
        submitAccess.process(commonDataBlock);
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logUtil.debug(this, "Error submitting application: "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Codes.RET_BYPASS_ALL_ADAPTORS;
    }
```

(That comment not quite right, the database transaction starts and ends at the 'process' method.)

So - when there IS an error in the code in 'process' it all 'gets rolled back' (quotes intentional). But when there's a database error such as FK problem or a NOT NULL column left as null, it's not rolled back.

The quotes are intentional above as I realise it's not actually rolling back successfully *from errors within 'process' method* like I thought, as it's not writing to the DB yet. Does this on exit.

The database error occurs 'between' the process method and the calling pojo. Hibernate has stored up first level data and starts writing to the database all the objects.

I've tried putting a try/catch around everything in 'process' method, but as there's no error occurring there (it's when it leaves the method the action starts!) then there's nothing thrown and caught.

The calling pojo does catch an error (and can see the data exception error for not null), but it has written objects to the database and left them there before the error.

The rollbackFor is good, but the fault seems to be after that - it catches errors IN that method, but when it leaves the method and Spring/Hibernate does its thing and commits... it's left on the database. No rollback. So rollbackFor only seems to work for errors in the associated method, not what happens automatically after (write behind)

Almost like autocommit behaviour, but shouldnt be the case with Hibernate (Oracle 10).

Any thoughts? I'll put a flush() in today to see if that makes the error occur WITHIN the process method and therefore caught by rollbackFor... but we shouldnt have to do this? (if that works)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Issue was I'd change the name of the transaction manager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager_guardianship"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory_guardianship" />
    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource_guardianship"/></property>
</bean>
```

I'd read somewhere if you don't have it as "transactionManager" it won't find it. Makes sense (I look up context stuff by name too! obvious!). I did this as I have two different ones for different databases.

So I added a qualifier:

```
<bean id="transactionManager_guardianship"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory_guardianship" />
    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource_guardianship"/></property>
    <qualifier value="txGuardianship"/>
</bean>
```

...and referred to the correct transaction in the service class:

```
@Transactional(value="txGuardianship", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly=false,rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public byte process(CommonDataBlock commonDataBlock) throws Exception   {
```

This is for when transaction manager name changed, plus (the reason it's change) when I have two of them. Similar @Transactional(value= setting for the other one.

Cheers